# Is there any option to select/ remove capabilities while using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

We are basically looking to remove the ofs_delta capability in libGit2Sharp while using it.
This requirement is because we want to directly consume the pack file generated from LibGit2Sharp and it will be easier and more reliable to do without ofs_delta commit objects.